# JVM halts without completing method will the local variable still remains in stack?

Tags: java

Local variables gets placed in stack when method is called and when JVM halts without completing the method, will the local variable still remain on the stack?

Example:

```
void Method() {
    int a=2;
    System.exit(0);
    Foo f=new Foo();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "halt"? If the JVM terminates, there will be nothing left in memory at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. After the `System.exit(0)` the system will clean-up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

When you restart the vm you will have fresh values and a fresh stack. Anything after a System.exit(0) won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

The Java-level stack will be gone, and the OS will free the memory.  However, nothing is going to actually zero it out so the stack variables will remain in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *stack* after the process exits, so there are certainly no local variables left on it, or anything else either.